# RTK Query - Empty error object with custom $.ajax() baseQuery funciton

Tags: react-redux, rtk-query

New to RTK Query and trying to create a custom `baseQuery` that uses `$.ajax()` instead of fetch. I have everything working for successful responses, however if an error occurs, the error object that is returned from the auto-generated api hook is always empty. I believe I've done everything asked [in the documentation here](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/customizing-queries#implementing-a-custom-basequery).

My API:

```
export const someApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'someApi',
  baseQuery: ajaxBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: 'someUrl'
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => {
    return {
      getSomeList: builder.query<void, void>({
        query: () => {
          return {
            url: 'someUrl'
          };
        },
      })
    };
  }
});

export const { useGetSomeListQuery } = someApi;
```

AjaxBaseQuery.ts:

```
export const ajaxBaseQuery = ({ baseUrl }: { baseUrl: string } = { baseUrl: '' }): BaseQueryFn<{
  url: string,
  method: string,
  params?: object,
  options: object
}> => {
  return ({
    url,
    method = 'PUT',
    params,
    options
  }) => {
    const ajaxOptions = {
      url: getUrl(baseUrl, url, (params as Record<string, string>)),
      type: method,
      ...options
    };

    return Promise.resolve($.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(getSuccess, (xhr: JQuery.jqXHR) => {
      return {
        error: {
          data: xhr.responseJSON
        }
      };
     });
   };
};
```

My component:

```
export default function GameScoresView(): JSX.Element {
  const queryObj = useGetSomeListQuery();
  const { data } = queryObj;
  ...
}
```

After the rejection occurs, I can see in my browser dev tools that RTK Query does in fact recognize that a rejection did occur, however the error object that I'm attempting to return in `AjaxBaseQuery.ts` is not there - instead just an empty object:

[image]

In my dev tools console, I do see `react_devtools_backend_compact.js` logging the error I was expecting from my `AjaxBaseQuery.ts` return:

[image]

I have tried stepping through some RTK Query source code to see if I can find a cause but finding that quite difficult. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After working a little more at this, for reasons unknown, using async/await in place of `Promise.resolve` works just fine in error scenarios. Got this idea after studying `fetchBaseQuery`'s source a little more closely:

```
export const ajaxBaseQuery = ({ baseUrl }: { baseUrl: string } = { baseUrl: '' }): BaseQueryFn<{
  url: string,
  method: string,
  params?: Record<string, string>,
  options: Record<string, unknown>
}> => {
  return async ({
    url,
    method = 'GET',
    params,
    options
  }) => {
    const ajaxOptions = {
      url: getUrl(baseUrl, url, params),
      type: method,
      ...options
    };

    let response;
    try {
      response = await $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
    } catch (e) {
       return {
         error: {
           data: xhr.responseJSON
         }
      }
    }

    return getSuccess(response);
  };
};
```